# How to animate height of fadeIn & toggle & fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how I could improve the code and how to animate the height of the `fadeIn/toggle`. There is a jerky movement to the height when you click a checkbox. I would like it to be a smooth slide up or down. I read that the jerky movement is because `jquery` doesn't know the height of the element being faded in or out. Am I on the right track?

**MyCode:**

```js
jQuery('.checkbox').on('change', function() {

  window.globalCheckboxValue = CheckBoxSwitch(jQuery(this).val());
  jQuery('.checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});

function CheckBoxSwitch(choice) {
  var text = "";
  var $selectList = jQuery('.selecrWrapper');
  var $datepicker = jQuery('.datepicker');
  switch (parseInt(choice)) {
    case 1:
      text = "Pedagog";
      if (!$datepicker.is(':visible') && !$selectList.is(':visible')) {
   
 jQuery(".selecrWrapper").animate({ marginTop: "100px" }, 1000, function () {
                    $datepicker.fadeIn(1000);
                });


      }

      if (!$datepicker.is(':visible') && $selectList.is(':visible')) {
        $selectList.fadeToggle(600, function() {
          $datepicker.fadeIn(1000);
        });
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      text = "Arrendator";
      if (!$datepicker.is(':visible') && !$selectList.is(':visible')) {
        $datepicker.fadeIn(1000);

      }

      if (!$datepicker.is(':visible') && $selectList.is(':visible')) {
        $selectList.fadeToggle(600, function() {
          $datepicker.fadeIn(1000);
        });
      }

      break;
    case 3:
      text = "Program";
      if (!$selectList.is(':visible') && !$datepicker.is(':visible')) {
        $selectList.fadeIn(1000);

      }

      if ($datepicker.is(':visible') && !$selectList.is(':visible')) {
        $datepicker.fadeToggle(600, function() {
          $selectList.fadeIn(1000);
        });
      }
      break;
  }

  return text;
}
```

```css
.calenderStyle {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="displayPedagog">
  <span>
                        Pedagog:
                    </span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1" />
</div>
<div class="marginArr">
  <span>
                        Arrendator
                    </span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="2" />
</div>
<div class="marginProg">
  <span>
                        Program
                    </span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="3" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="slectanddateWrapper">
  <!-- DatePicker -->
  <div class="datepicker" style="display:none;">PlaceHolderDatePicker</div>
  <!-- DatePicker -->
  <!-- SelectList -->
  <div class="selecrWrapper" style="display:none;">
    <label class="selectLabelProgram">Välj det program du tillhör: </label>
    <select class="form-control selectProgram" id="selectList"></select>
  </div>
  <!-- SelectList -->
</div>
<div class="calenderStyle">
  <!-- calender -->
  <div id='calendar'>CalenderPlaceHolder</div>
  <!-- calender -->
</div>
```

Comment: The height difference is because of the select. You could try using `slideUp` and `slideDown` to toggle the element working on its height.

Comment: I updated the code with animate. But cant get the animate to move. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think some of the animate options require jquery ui

Comment: I am using jquery UI DatePicker. so I got the Jquery-ui script loaded

Comment: dumb me lol, well try using slideUp and slideDown, not the animate, but the function itself. Like `$('#bla').slideUp()`

Comment: But I Chaged to slideUp() and slideDown() as you suggested. And it works. It basiclly does what I want with slight modifications

Comment: Thanks for your help. make an answer and I will mak it as aswerd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height difference is happening because the `<select/>` has more height than the `<span/>`.

You can try using [**`slideUp()`**](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) or [**`slideDown()`**](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) to achieve a smoother transition.

If you prefer using toggle, you can use [**`slideToggle()`**](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/).